# Returning an autorelease'd CFTypeRef with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

I am new to Automatic Reference Counting with LLVM and Objective-C, and have a question about returning CGImageRefs from my Objective-C function. In the days of manual reference counting, it was possible to simply cast the CGImageRef to an `id`, autorelease it, then return the original CGImageRef. With ARC, I am aware that you can direct the ARC system to autorelease and return your retainable object, but I do not see a way of doing this for CFTypeRefs.

Here is what I could do with ARC disabled:

```
- (CGImageRef)image {
    CGImageRef myImage;
    id myImageID = (id)myImage;
    [myImageID autorelease];
    return myImage;
}
```

So, I want to essentially create a method that, using ARC, returns a CGImageRef that is not owned by the caller. If there is a better way of doing the same thing, I am all open to ideas. I know that `UIImage` does something of this sort with the `CGImage` property.

**Edit:** Although disabling ARC for a specific file is a valid method of doing this, I'd prefer to use pure ARC throughout my code. This comes in handy when sharing specific code for specific files with others, since they will not need to change build settings for any given file.  In order to leverage the ARC system to autorelease a CFTypeRef, you can do this:

```
__attribute__((ns_returns_autoreleased))
id CGImageReturnAutoreleased (CGImageRef original) {
    // CGImageRetain(original);
    return (__bridge id)original;
}
```

And then simply do `return (__bridge CGImageRef)CGImageReturnAutoreleased(myImage)` to return an autorelease'd image.

Comment: I had a very similar problem, but when I implemented that function and tried to use it like you did, the analyzer in Xcode said it was leaking. Instead, I changed the name of my method to start with new (- (CFTypeRef)newCFTypeObject), so it follows the naming convention to return a retained object. Isn't there any pretty way of returning an autoreleased CFType? (without having all kinds of helper functions or external files)

Comment: I use your code, the same, it have leak.

Comment: I would recommend rather than being lazy, just insert the proper CFRelease in the right place. It saves typing and makes your code readable for others. When you can start with an NS type and use toll free bridging without changing ownership, you're ok. Otherwise you're polluting the water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### UPDATE

As of OS X 10.9 and iOS 7.0, the public SDK includes a `CFAutorelease` function.

#### ORIGINAL

You could create a utility function like this:

```
void cfAutorelease(CFTypeRef *ref) {
    [[(id)ref retain] autorelease];
}
```

and put it in a file that you compile with ARC disabled.  You need to pass the compiler flag `-fno-objc-arc` to disable ARC for that file.  In Xcode 4, select your project, then the Build Phases tab.  Open the Compile Sources section.  Double-click the file that contains the utility function and put `-fno-objc-arc` in the popup box.

Comment: You're not really doing it with ARC - you're doing it without. Would be nice if there was an easier way to do it.

Comment: Uh, that's quite a hack. It works, but I wouldn't recommend that. Use __attribute__((ns_returns_autoreleased)) if you *really* need it autoreleased.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `ARC` do not worry about `autoreleasing` the object,

```
UIImage *image;
image.CGImage
```

always returns the `autorelease` object itself.

Comment: It can tool free bridged using __bridge